# mix numeric key and string key at YAML collection type in Symfony

Tags: symfony, yaml

I define a php array with YAML like following

```
groups:
        - 'Order'
        - 'Adjustment'
        - 'CarModel'
        - 'Address'
        - 'OrderItem'
        -  items:
            - OrderItem
            - Product
            - product:
                - Simple
            - service:
                - Simple
```

the php companion is

```
$groups = [
     'Order',
     'Adjustment',
     'CarModel',
     'Address',
     'OrderItem',
     'items' => [
         'OrderItem',
         'Product',
         'product' => ['Simple'],
         'service' => ['Simple'],
     ]
 ];
```

Symfony transforms the YAML format to a numeric array, the php one is a associative array, that is their array_keys are different. any way to define associative array with YAML in Symfony?

Comment: Could past the result you are getting !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself

```
groups:
    0: 'Order'
    1: 'Adjustment'
    2: 'CarModel'
    3: 'Address'
    4: 'OrderItem'
    items:
        0: Product
        1: Service
        2: OrderItem
        product: ['Simple']
        service: [ 'Simple']
```